# stomp+ActiveMQ with SSL

Tags: javascript, ssl, https, activemq-classic, stomp

I have used stomp+ActiveMQ in my application to push the data events received from external applications. I am able to setup this on HTTP [ws] but when I tried moving this setup to my production server where we have HTTPS [wss], the setup is failing with error saying un-authorised access. I understand it is because of the SSL what we have on production server, but I am unable to find out solution for this, I tried searching and tried following the proposed solutions but none are working. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Update 1: Adding the details asked

Here is the code what I have added for STOMP
var client = Stomp.client("wss://domain:61614/stomp");

And the error I get is "ReferenceError: Stomp is not defined"

activemq : 5.9.0
STOM     : 1.0.9

Comment: without AMQ version, configs, error logs it is not easy to help you.

Comment: Not an answer, but I configured an Nginx reverse proxy that terminated the TLS session and passed the plain websocket connection to AMQ. That way I could manage the same certificate as for a related website in one place. It also offloads AMQ with TLS stuff. No reason it shouldn't work though

Comment: @HassenBennour : I have added the information you have asked for, I hope it might help you to answer my question.

Comment: @PetterNordlander: Thank you for your comment, I tried it but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, and it was related to the key strokes what I had generated earlier. I just deleted the previous one and recreated a new one for my SSL and everything started working with the sample application provided by STOMP team. I will integrate it in my actual project and will paste the solution here for everyone use.

Following are the settings we had used.

transportConnector name="wss" uri="wss://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=500000000&wireFormat.maxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=36000000&websocket.maxIdleTime=0&transport.useInactivityMonitor=false"

Answer (score 0):

it's a js side log, did you have included your js stomp file ??

```
<script src='stomp.js'></script>
```

https://github.com/apache/activemq/tree/master/activemq-web-demo/src/main/webapp/websocket

Comment: I have used STOMP from following link : http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/ and the stomp.js version from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/master/lib/stomp.js". Also I have included the file as you have asked above

Comment: I resolved the issue, and it was related to the key strokes what I had generated earlier. I just deleted the previous one and recreated a new one for my SSL and everything started working with the sample application provided by STOMP team. I will integrate it in my actual project and will paste the solution here for everyone use.